# dhcpcd keeps giving me a deprecated IPv6 address form my ISP

Tags: dhcp, ipv6

My ISP (EPB in Tennessee) recently rolled out IPv6. I had [my router setup for IPv6](https://battlepenguin.com/tech/setting-up-ipv6-on-a-linux-router/) from a previous ISP, so it worked immediately at first.

But then, `dnsmasq` stopped sending out router advertisements, because the prefix-delegation I was requesting for my internal network was getting set to `deprecated` for some reason (IP redacted):

```
7: brlan: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:90:0b:3c:60:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.1/24 scope global brlan
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2605:8600:***:****::1/64 scope global deprecated dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 44826sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fe80::290:bff:fe3c:6037/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If I run `ip -6 addr change 2605:8600:***:****::1 dev brlan preferred_lft forever` and restart `dnsmasq`, it starts sending out router advertisements again. However, it will eventually go back to `deprecated`. In my configuration, if1 is the WAN adapter and brlan is a bridge over two ports I use for the internal LAN. The following is my `dhcpcd.conf`

```
controlgroup wheel
duid
persistent
vendorclassid
nooption domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
option host_name
option rapid_commit

require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
interface if1
  metric 100
interface wwan0
  metric 500
noipv6rs                 # disable routing solicitation
denyinterfaces brlan      # Don't touch eth2 at all
interface if1
  metric 100
  ipv6rs                 # enable routing solicitation for eth0
  ia_na 1                # request an IPv6 address
  ia_pd 2 brlan/0        # request a PD and assign it to eth1
```

I understand IPv6 is designed to rotate addresses for privacy. Shouldn't my `brlan` adapter be getting two IPv6 addresses then, one that's preferred and one that's deprecated? Is my dhcpcd configuration incorrect for getting a correct delegation block for my local lan?

Comment: It seem you are using random addressing with privacy extensions. You will change addresses on a periodic basis. You could change your OS to not use that. The Deprecated address is one that was changed due to using the privacy extensions.

Comment: Are you sure that's what's going on? I didn't run into this with my last ISP. If I lookup `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/brland/use_tempaddr` the value is `0`. Same for `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/if1/use_tempaddr`. I don't think I'm using temp addresses. Maybe that's the issue and I should turn those on with `sysctl`? If I do use temp addresses, shouldn't `dhcpcd` assign two addresses to `brlan` with different `valid_lft` and `preferred_lft` lengths?

Comment: This is the type of thing that I get for privacy extensions: `Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2001:db8:dead:beef:c04:b4d8:9813:7e02(Deprecated)`. Look at https://support.binarylane.com.au/support/solutions/articles/1000100519-disable-ipv6-privacy-extension-in-linux

Comment: Both `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.use_tempaddr` and `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.default.use_tempaddr` return 0, so neither of those are enabled. I tried enabling them too and `dhcpcd` still gives me deprecated addresses.

Comment: Also seeing dnsmasq handing out deprecated IPv6 addresses to a MacOS machine, which are unroutable. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @GrahamLeggett I think this was due to my ISP and maybe they were trying to reverse their IPv6 rollout to fix issues? A few weeks after, I started getting IPv6 address assignments that dnsmasq could fully assign out to the whole network. I can now do IPv6/v4 file. If you're running into this, it might be a per-ISP issue. ‍♂️